# Need to get output of all weekdays starting from given date

Tags: python-3.x

Output is not how it should be

```
given_day = datetime.date(2022,10,31)
    dates = given_day + datetime.timedelta(days=+1)
    for i in range(0 - given_day.weekday(), 7 - given_day.weekday()):
        print(given_day.strftime("%A"))
```

Output should start from Monday and end to Sunday
Output I get is:
Monday
Monday
Monday
Monday
Monday
Monday
Monday
Where i made a mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't make head or tail of your code, but the following works:

```py
given_day = datetime.date(2022,10,31)
for i in range(0 + given_day.weekday(), 7):
    print(given_day.strftime("%A"))
    given_day += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```